# Angular Unit Test Video Resolution

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, dom, jasmine

I am checking the video resolution of a video file. The code is working well and now I am stuck at unit testing this function.

I tried spying on videoWidth & videoHeight properties with no success. Instead I got error messages saying these properties do not exist. The problem that I found is that the HTMLVideoElement's videoWidth and videoHeight properties are read-only. How can I test it ?

TS

```
videoResolutionTest(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
        const currentVideo = evt.target as HTMLVideoElement;

        if ((currentVideo.videoWidth <= 720) && (currentVideo.videoHeight <=500 540)) {
            this.displayError('resolutionError', 2000);
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<video (loadedmetadata)="videoResolutionTest($event)">
<source type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: you and me both :)))) god it's annoying nothing obvious is in any SO answer that I can find

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mocked event object and cast the type of it.  The mocked event contains a target that has different resolutions.

unit test solution using angular v11+:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  template: `
    <video (loadedmetadata)="videoResolutionTest($event)">
      <source type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  `,
})
export class VideoComponent {
  videoResolutionTest(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    const currentVideo = evt.target as HTMLVideoElement;

    if (currentVideo.videoWidth <= 720 && currentVideo.videoHeight <= 540) {
      this.displayError('resolutionError', 2000);
    }
  }

  displayError(arg0: string, arg1: number) {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { VideoComponent } from './example.component';

fdescribe('55416150', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VideoComponent>;
  let component: VideoComponent;
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [VideoComponent],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VideoComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    })
  );
  it('should display error', () => {
    const evt = {
      target: {
        videoWidth: 400,
        videoHeight: 300,
      },
    };
    const displayErrorStub = spyOn(component, 'displayError').and.stub();
    component.videoResolutionTest((evt as unknown) as KeyboardEvent);
    expect(displayErrorStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith('resolutionError', 2000);
  });

  it('should do nothing', () => {
    const evt = {
      target: {
        videoWidth: 1024,
        videoHeight: 768,
      },
    };
    const displayErrorStub = spyOn(component, 'displayError').and.stub();
    component.videoResolutionTest((evt as unknown) as KeyboardEvent);
    expect(displayErrorStub).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

[image]